# Calculating mean of a specific column by specific rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like in the pictures.[image]

Now, I want to add a new column that will show the average of power for each day (given the data is sampled every 5 minutes), but separately for when it is day_or_night (day = 0 in the column, night = 1). I've gotten this far:

`train['avg_by_day'][train['day_or_night']==1] = train['power'][train['day_or_night']==1].mean()
train['avg_by_day'][train['day_or_night']==0] = train['power'][train['day_or_night']==0].mean()`

but this just adds the average of all the power values that correspond to day, or similarly - night, which isn't what I'm after: a specific average for each day/night separately.

I need something like: train['avg_by_day'] == train.power.mean() when day == 1 and day_or_night == 1, and this for each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to group the dataframe by `day` and `day_or_night` and create a new column with mean `power` values for each group:

```
train['avg_by_day'] = train.groupby(['day','day_or_night'])['power']\
                           .transform('mean')
```

Maybe you should also include `year` and `month` in the grouping columns because otherwise it's going to group the 1st day of every month together, same for the 2nd day and so on.

Comment: Good thinking! Would I group the year and month as well if I simply wrote:

`train['avg_by_day'] = train.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day','day_or_night'])['power']\
                           .transform('mean')`

Comment: Yes, just add them in `groupby` :).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :)